# Sandboxing user written code on python without containerizing

Tags: python, sandbox

I am making leetcode alike website and on backend I need to sandbox user's code to protect resources without using Docker or sth like containerizing. What are the best ways to protect my system from user executing code? Like if user import os and os.remove it is fatal to my system.

I need an approach or implementation of sandboxing or protecting techniques.